# How to build a NodeJS variable to create a regexp query for ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm working at a company that used to have a monolithic PHP/MySQL CMS which controlled the website, but we are now trying to get the website to pull data from our API rather than directly from MySQL. The API is simply ElasticSearch on AWS. I wrote some code which now moves our data from MySQL to ElasticSearch. And now I can get the data I want with a curl call like this:

```
curl --verbose  -d    '{"from" : 0, "size" : 10000, "query": {   "bool": {     "should": [   {    "regexp": {     "string-of-words-associated-with-this-document": {      "value": ".*steel.*"     }    }   },    {    "regexp": {     "string-of-words-associated-with-this-document": {      "value": ".*services.*"     }    }   }     ]    }   }  }'    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET "https://search-sameday01-ntsw7b7shy3wu.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/crawlers/_search?pretty=true"
```

This works great. Each document in ElasticSearch has a field that contains the words we want to query against, and we match against that field using regexp queries.

Now I'm writing a new app that checks data coming in from our web crawlers, and looks to see if we have certain names already in our database. The new app is a NodeJS app, so I decided to use this library:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js

I need to build up what might be many regexp clauses, so I go into a loop and build up many clauses in an array:

```
 array_of_elasticsearch_clauses_should_match.push( {    "regexp": {     "string-of-words-associated-with-this-document": {      "value": ".*" + word_sanitized + ".*"     }    }   } );
```

So I thought I could then pass in this variable like this:

```
es_client.search({
    index: 'crawlers',
    type: 'sameday',
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                should: array_of_elasticsearch_clauses_should_match
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function (resp) {
```

But I get this error:

```
Trace: [parsing_exception] [array_of_elasticsearch_clauses_should_match] query malformed, no start_object after query name, with { line=1 & col=75 }
```

How could I build up the regexp clauses in a variable and then pass it in?

Comment: Just ran your code - it works great for me with AWS elasticsearch.
I'm using aws-es, which is similar to the 'elasticsearch' module.

I would remove the .* before and after the reg-exp.

Comment: You don't know why I would get "no start_object after query name"?

Comment: The ".*" are regexp expressions meant to get it to match against any occurrence of the word.

Comment: To be clear, my curl call works perfectly. It's the Javascript that doesn't work.

Comment: what ES version are you running?
what node module version are you using?
I think that's where the problem is.